# How do you create a map/reduce index with multiple groupings in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

We are storing a set of documents in Raven.

```
public class MyDocument
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string DocumentType { get; set; }
  public int ClientId { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

And we want to display a report of Documents grouped by both the ClientId and DocumentType so that looks like:

```
DocumentType  ClientHasManyOfThese Count Action
------------- -------------------- ----- ---------------------
DocumentType1 Yes                  10    LinkToListOfDocuments
DocumentType1 No                   5     LinkToListOfDocuments
DocumentType2 Yes                  12    LinkToListOfDocuments
DocumentType2 No                   15    LinkToListOfDocuments
```

I have created the following index but it is only returning the correct results for small numbers of documents.

```
public class MyDocumentCount
{
  public string DocumentType { get; set; }
  public int ClientId { get; set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
  public bool MultipleDocumentsForClient { get; set; }
}

public class MyIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyDocument, MyDocumentCount>
{
  public MyIndex()
  {
    Map = tasks => 
      from task in tasks
      where task.Status = "Show In Report"
      select new MyDocumentCount
      {
        DocumentType = task.DocumentType,
        ClientId = task.ClientId,
        MultipleDocumentsForClient = false,
        Count = 1
      };

    Reduce = results =>
      results.GroupBy(result => new 
      {
        result.DocumentType, 
        result.ClientId
      }).Select(conDocGrp => new MyDocumentCount 
      {
        DocumentType = conDocGrp.Key.DocumentType,
        Count = conDocGrp.Sum(result => result.Count),
        MultipleDocumentsForClient = conDocGrp.Sum(result => result.Count) > 1,
        ClientId = conDocGrp.Key.ClientId
      });

    TransformResults = (database, results) =>
      results.GroupBy(result => new
      {
        result.DocumentType,
        result.MultipleDocumentsForClient
      }).Select(multDocGrp => new
      {
        multDocGrp.Key.DocumentType,
        multDocGrp.Key.MultipleDocumentsForClient,
        Count = multDocGrp.Sum(result => int.Parse(result.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))),
        ClientId = 0
      });
  }
}
```

I believe that it has something to do with the result count limit in Raven when calling:

```
var results = session.Query<MyDocumentCount, MyIndex>().ToList();
```

Maybe the limit is applied to the index results before performing the transform?

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and if there is a way to achieve what I am wanting?

We are currently running RavenDB (Server Build 2380).

Thanks.

Comment: why are you converting an _int_ into a _string_ and then back into an _int_?
`int.Parse(result.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Why do you have in your example as Count = '5' for DocumentType2 and ClientHasManyOfThese = No, when in your index MultipleDocumentsForClient is true when it's more than 1.

Comment: Sorry about the int.Parse(....) I honestly cannot remember the reasoning behind this. I pulled this code from our codebase and I think there was some weird thing in the background that this solved. It would look more simple as Count = multDocGrp.Sum(result => result.Count)

Comment: The idea behind the question is: I have a list of print document requests (MyDocument) of which there are multiple types (i.e. Status Notification, New Purchase, etc.) and I want to generate a Report that shows the count of MyDocuments grouped by DocumentType but also grouped by if a customer has multiple requests of the same type (hence the ClientHasManyOfThese). Does this clarify the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the basic gist of the problem from what I can gather is that you're trying to aggregate an aggregation. Specifically, you're trying to group by `ClientId` and `DocumentType` and then you're trying to aggregate those results by `MultipleDocumentsForClient`. Your index works on most cases but when the Reduce produces more results than the default RavenDB 'page size' limit, you don't get the desired outputs.

I confirmed that the `TransformResults` only receives up to the page limit size from RavenDB. You can think of `TransformResults` as executing on the client side to make sure you don't make any mistakes later. Maybe that's why it was deprecated and we should use Transformers instead.

To solve your problem right now, I think you're doing too much in one index. The transformer part is not really used to transform the results from the query, instead it's being used to aggregate again.
If you can't do all the aggregation in the Reduce portion of the index, then I recommend that you try to split the index into two smaller indexes. Perhaps in this case, one index could be for when the client has multiple docs and one could be for when the client has single docs. Then you would have to load both results into memory, which seems to suit your case since you were already using `.ToList` on your query.